# Uploading a cv::Mat to D3D texture using PInvoke in Unity3D

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, directx, directx-11

SITUATION

I have an industrial GigE camera. GigE or USB or any other interface does not matter here. The point is that the camera is not to be considered a Webcam since it has its own driver. Using that camera SDK, I can read out images into a cv::Mat with OpenCV then convert, undistort and do some other processing stuff on these images. This works OK.

Then, I want to use that camera to texture a quad in Unity3D (OS = Windows) in real time. I have wrote a DLL that copies images into a Texture2D using the CPU and that DLL is called using PInvoke in Unity3D. The pipeline is:

1. one image is read out from camera's sensor into a cv::Mat;
2. the cv::Mat is copied into a unmanaged buffer (buffer in Unity3D unmanaged memory);
3. the unmanaged buffer is marshaled into a managed buffer;
4. the managed buffer is loaded (copied) into a Texture2D internal buffer by calling LoadRawTextureData(byte[] managedBuffer);
5. the Texture2D internal buffer is uploaded to the GPU by calling Apply.

I did notice while writing this question that a Texture2D has another form (new since I wrote the DLL I believe) for loading its internal buffer from a unmanaged buffer : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html

Thus, steps 2 and 3 could be removed but one still has to load the Texture2D internal buffer before uploading to the GPU.

PROBLEM

I want to evacuate the CPU as much as possible from the pipeline. **I want to upload the cv::Mat directly into the Texture2D in GPU.**

There is this Texture2D method to get the native texture pointer on the GPU: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture.GetNativeTexturePtr.html

I am not sure how to handle it. I know some basic stuff in Direct3D (D3D11 in particular) but I am no expert. Can anyone please do explain with or without code how to copy some cv::Mat to some D3D11 (or D3D12 for Windows 10) texture?

Comment: the first good Unity question on the whole site